# Ubuntu Server: Limit total downloaded data per client

Tags: networking, server

I have an Ubuntu server set up as a gateway for lots of clients, which connects them to the Internet.

I want to impose transmitted data limits on each of the clients (or IP address), e.g. 10 MBytes/day. How do I do that?

On the server, I run Squid as a transparent caching HTTP proxy, and a set of iptables rules that restrict some of the users from accessing the Internet at all. If I could use one of these apps for the limiting, it would be great. Or is it possible with tc? I'm not familiar with it, so I'd appreciate a more detailed answer if using tc.

I've seen questions here like https://serverfault.com/questions/116091/how-to-limit-user-quota-bandwidth-to-10gb-day - this one is too specific just for PHP servers. Other questions mainly ask about limiting transfer rate (kbps), but not total transferred data limits. I want to provide my users full available bandwidth, but only 10 MBytes of it a day.

Thank you for ideas.